# JMAIL: Multiple Recipient

Tags: asp.net, email, asp-classic, jmail

Does JMail accepts delimiter(;) or comma(,) as a separator between different email address like CDO.Message.

For example, we can write,

> Mail.To="a@a.com,b@b.com"  in CDO.Message.

Does the same is valid for JMAIL like the one below.

> jMail.AddRecipient ("a@a.com,b@b.com")

I know we can add multiple recipients by calling the AddRecipient again and again but my question is can we do it in a single line like in CDO.Message?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add multiple recipients by calling the AddRecipient

Comment: which character should I use to separate two emails.
Is it comma(,) or semicolon(;)

Comment: I don't know the Jmail component, buyt couldn't you just try both methods and see what happens.  You'll either receive two emails or get an error message

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

I spent some time figuring this out as well. I tried the recommended array() of recipients but that did not seem to work. The only thing which worked for me so far was a properly formatted multiple recipient string:

```
$jmail->addRecipient('recipient1@site.com','recipient2@site.com','recipient3@site.com');
```

Please note the ["] markup. If you replace the ["] with ['] it will not work. It's little "delicate" this way :)

I am using jMail with PHP/COM extension but I am sure you can reuse this principle for ASP or any other language.

I hope this helped.